# How to deep learn from a row of numbers using Node.js and convnetjs and predicted a new value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, deep-learning

I try to to use [convnetjs](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/) to make Node.js learn from a row of numbers in `x,y` coordiinates. The goal is to predicted next value in a simple number row.

First of all a very simple row `[0,1,0,2,0,3,0,4,0,5,0,6]` maybe later `sin` and `cos` number row.

I do not want to go to deep into the deep learning materia so I am using convnetjs.

So far I tried :

```
var convnetjs = require("./convnet-min.js");

// create a net out of it
var net = new convnetjs.Net();

var layer_defs = [];
layer_defs.push({type:'input', out_sx:1, out_sy:1, out_depth:1});
layer_defs.push({type:'fc', num_neurons:5, activation:'sigmoid'});
layer_defs.push({type:'regression', num_neurons:1});
var net = new convnetjs.Net();
net.makeLayers(layer_defs);

var my_data = [
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
];

var x = new convnetjs.Vol(my_data);

var trainer = new convnetjs.SGDTrainer(net, {learning_rate:1.1, momentum:0.0, batch_size:1, l2_decay:0.001});

var think = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < my_data.length; i++) {
        x.w[i] = my_data[i]; // Vol.w is just a list, it holds your data
        trainer.train(x, my_data[i]);
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    think();
    var predicted_values = net.forward(x);
    console.log('predicted value: ' + predicted_values.w[0]);
}
```

To realize learning I want to predict the next value, but I wonder (knowing the next value [9]) how to tell the trainer he did a bad, good or very good job?

What this the right way to train `x` more to predict a value? I guess this is not trivial as that because the predicted value goes not into direction of value  `9` ^^.

Comment: This should be included in the .train function already otherwise search if you have a backward function or something like that, net learn by forwadding values to the net and then backwarding the differential error. However i don't think your example of data really suits. Try to generate sets that follow normal distribution, this is what you have with real problems mainly and for what those tool has been developped and optimized for.

Comment: can you specify how is your input data and what is the output expected? I don't see the relation between the statement in your question and the format of `my_data`

Comment: My_data is a row of numbers starting at 0 up to 10 then restart at 0 and again and again. The next prdicted value I expect is 9.

Comment: What I mean is that you need to have the input well defined (in a domain space, which are the features?) in order to determine properly the input layer or the net. Then you have to train the net telling the real value for each item in the domain. If you define a domain of 1x1xn (n means the length of you row) then you can train the net with rows of size n and an expected value for each row. In your case you are creating a domain of 1x1x86 (86 = `my_data.length`), so you have only one item with 86 features and you are training this item 100 times with different values each time.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but have no idea how to define```input``` and ```net``` well . Can you provide some example code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a domain space input for your data. After that follow this steps:

- Create a network according to the domain previously defined (please read this documentation to tune the parameter in the network: [convnetjs-doc](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/docs.html)).
- Train the network, please also refer to the [convnetjs-doc](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/docs.html) in order of select proper values for the parameters of the trainer.

The follow example show you a network assuming that the domain space is 9 (the network must predict the next value for one row of size 9). I'm using the same data set for training (`my_data`), so to meet the domain space requirement in each data item I'm taking arrays of size 9 in each step in the training process from `my_data` (using the `slice` function) and assuming that the real value for each row is the next value in `my_data` after take an array of size 9 (if the data set change you should take a different approach to create items that meet the same domain space requirement).

The function `learn` do the learning process described above, `var data = my_data.slice(i, i + d);` take an array of size `d` (9 in this example) from `my_data` starting at `i`, so we are moving through the data training set and taking slices of size 9 (to meet the domain space requirement). After that we get the real value for `data` with this: `var real_value = [my_data[i + d]];` which is the value next to the last in `data`, note that since we are working with `regression` the real_value must be a LIST (see [convnetjs-doc](http://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/docs.html) for more details). Then we create a [Vol class](https://github.com/karpathy/convnetjs/blob/master/src/convnet_vol.js) `var x = new convnetjs.Vol(data);` to storage the data, and finally we train the net setting the real value `real_value` for the previously created [Vol class](https://github.com/karpathy/convnetjs/blob/master/src/convnet_vol.js) `trainer.train(x, real_value);`.

When we finish the learning process we are ready for predict some values, all we have to do is create a new input, using a [Vol class](https://github.com/karpathy/convnetjs/blob/master/src/convnet_vol.js) and predict with the trained net.

This is the code:

```
var convnetjs = require('convnetjs');

// create a net out of it
var net = new convnetjs.Net();
var d = 9;
var layer_defs = [];
layer_defs.push({type:'input', out_sx:1, out_sy:1, out_depth:d});
layer_defs.push({type:'fc', num_neurons:10, activation:'sigmoid'});
layer_defs.push({type:'regression', num_neurons:1});
var net = new convnetjs.Net();
net.makeLayers(layer_defs);

var my_data = [
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
    0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
];



var trainer = new convnetjs.SGDTrainer(net, {learning_rate:0.01, momentum:0.2, batch_size:1, l2_decay:0.001});

var learn = function () {
  for(var j = 0; j < 100; j++){
    for (var i = 0; i < my_data.length - d; i++) {
        var data = my_data.slice(i, i + d);
        var real_value = [my_data[i + d]];
        var x = new convnetjs.Vol(data);
        trainer.train(x, real_value);
        var predicted_values = net.forward(x);
        console.log("data: [" + data + "] -> value: " + real_value);
        console.log("prediction in learn stage is: " + predicted_values.w[0]);
    }
  }

}

var predict = function(data){
  var x = new convnetjs.Vol(data);
  var predicted_value = net.forward(x);
  return predicted_value.w[0];
}

learn();
var item = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
console.log("predicted value for [" + item + "] is: " + predict(item));
```

These are some example output:

```
predicted value for [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0] is: 1.0789064579041727
predicted value for [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] is: 9.223386915148865
predicted value for [10,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] is: 8.430232430080627
predicted value for [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] is: 9.020852169040044
predicted value for [5,6,7,8,9,10,0,1,2] is: 3.0623065881421674
predicted value for [4,5,6,7,8,9,10,0,1] is: 2.208646113846295
```